# looping each row of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe and I want to divide values of the same row by eachother if a certain condition is met and create a new column for each condition.

I tried all kinds of loops but Im getting the error that the truth value of a series is ambiguos. I think Im close to the solution but I cant quite figure out the quickest way.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'colA': np.random.randn(20), 'colB': np.random.randn(20), 'colC': np.random.randn(20)})
print(df)
x = 0
y = 0.5
for ix, r in df.iterrows():
    if (r['colA'] > x) & (r['colA'] < y):    
        df.loc[ix,str(y)] = df.loc[ix,'colA']/df.loc[ix,'colB']
        x += 0.5
        y += 0.5
```

This is how far I got now. Problematic is, that x and y increase after each row for which the condition is met. But I need the division to be carried out for ALL the rows where the condition is met, and THEN increase x and y.

Comment: It would be useful to post code to build an example dataframe along with the expected result...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use iterrows if you want the division to be applied to all the lines meeting the condition. Here is a fixed version of your initial code:

```
while x <= df['colA'].max():
    sub = df.loc[(df['colA'] > x)&(df['colA'] < y)]  # filter the dataframe on both conditions
    df.loc[sub.index, str(y)] = df['colA']/df['colB']
    x += .5
    y += .5
```

Answer (score 0):

The two conditions of the while loop need to be wrapped in `all()` (or the corresponding pandas function) to explicitly check if all values of the resulting boolean array are true.

Comment: While this is true, it is not what OP is trying to do, so does not really provide an answer to the problem. The problem here is that there's no `row` indexing, among others